# keep my class name in active nivoSlider image

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I am trying to use nivoSlider (jQuery plugin) on an existing site...and i use a class to help with the style of the images in the slideshow.  For example, my list of images would contain multiple classes like this:

```
<img class="active rounded" src="...
```

I have nivoSlider working fine, and my first image starts with class name "active" as shown...and ALL the images in my slideshow contain the class "rounded".  It seems that as jQuery advanced through the images for the slideshow, it (obviously) applies the "active" class to the image in order to have it show up.  The problem is (it appears to me) that when this "Active" class is applied, my existing class "rounded" is removed...so rather than nice round corners, i have square corners.  Does anyone know if there is somewhere within nivoSlider that i can specify that the "active" image should ALSO have/maintain the "rounded" class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manuall edit the nivo-slider js file and find

```
sliderImg.attr('src', vars.currentImage.attr('src'))...
```

and add the next piece behind it in each line that starts off like above

```
.attr('class', vars.currentImage.attr('class'))
```

so the result becomes something like this:

```
sliderImg.attr('src', vars.currentImage.attr('src')).attr('class', vars.currentImage.attr('class'))...
```

and then you need to scan the file for

```
slider.append(
    $('<div class="nivo-box" name="'+ cols +'" rel="'+ rows +'"><img src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'" style="position:absolute; width:'+ slider.width() +'px; height:auto; display:block; top:-'+ (boxHeight*rows) +'px; left:-'+ (boxWidth*cols) +'px;" /></div>').css({ 
        opacity:0,
        left:(boxWidth*cols)+'px', 
        top:(boxHeight*rows)+'px',
        width:(slider.width()-(boxWidth*cols))+'px'

    })
);
```

or similar. The important part that you need to make sure is the same is

```
<img src="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'"
```

behind that part you need to add:

```
 class="'+ vars.currentImage.attr('class') +'"
```

Comment: WOW...many months have passed since this question... I am not still using nivo on that project, but will try to test this out elsewhere to see how it works.  This could be VERY useful in the future.  I will keep you posted on my success (or failure).  THANKS!

Comment: I discovered this since I had the same problem (well, I wanted to preserve the name attribute but it works the same way) and after I finally found the answer I thought I'd share it here :p